# linux, запись в FrameBuffer

Tags: c++, linux

Я довольно длительное время практиковал запись в FrameBuffer на своем смартфоне из TWRP.
Это работает отлично, перенес этот же код на свой Linux - ошибка.

```
ioctl(FrameBufferOpennedFile, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &OrigVarInfo) // return 0
```

Я не могу получить эти данные, а они мне критично важны.

Код:

```
        /* открываем устройство FrameBuffer */
        FrameBufferFD = open(DEV_FB, O_RDWR);
        if (FrameBufferFD < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error opening %s\n", DEV_FB);
            exit(1);
        }

        /* получаем фиксированую информацию об экране */
        if (ioctl(FrameBufferFD, FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO, &FixedInfo)) // <- это
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: ioctl(FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO) failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
```

Comment: что в `DEV_FB`? права на `/dev/fb0` есть? открытие точно проходит успешно? что в `errno` после неудачного `ioctl`? в консоль фреймбуферную переключился? иксы пробовал останавливать? какая железка графикой заправляет? какие дрова к ней?

Comment: Иксы - причина всего, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Остановить работу Xorg. `sudo killall X`